# "Symbol uhd::stream_cmd_t::STREAM_MODE_START_CONTINUOUS could not be resolved"

Tags: c++, enums, eclipse-cdt, redhawksdr

I am working with Redhawk trying to get a device built to run the USRP x310 as a reciver through redhawk.  I'm trying to use the USRP source code from https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/USRP_UHD.  The device was built with no errors but had some issues with functionality when I went to us it.  When I went back to the source to see about correcting the issues it was showing errors in the code (this was before making any changes).  There are two instances of the error and they are the only errors in the code.  It's when I try to access the `uhd::stream_cmd_t enum`.  If I right click and say "View Source" it points at exactly what I'm trying to acess but the error continues to say the symbol cannot be resolved.  I've double checked that the library is linked in correctly as well as double checking the syntax for accessing an enum inside of a struct.  Any ideas on what this error is and how to fix it would be great.

Addition Information:

The REDHAWK version is 1.10.0R201407290010

the RPMs that show up from the grep request are:

[redhawk@localhost ~]$ rpm -qa | egrep -i redhawk
redhawk-libVITA49_v1-2.0.0-10.el6.x86_64
RedhawkDevUtils_v1-3.0.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-ide-1.10.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-libVITA49_v1-debuginfo-2.0.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-sdrroot-dom-profile-1.10.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-sdrroot-dom-mgr-1.10.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-libVITA49_v1-devel-2.0.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-1.10.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-devel-1.10.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-debuginfo-1.10.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-basic-components-1.10.0-10.el6.x86_64
RedhawkDevUtils_v1-devel-3.0.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-sdrroot-dev-mgr-1.10.0-10.el6.x86_64
RedhawkDevUtils_v1-debuginfo-3.0.0-10.el6.x86_64
redhawk-codegen-1.10.0-10.el6.noarch
(I left the UHD off as it pulled in a lot more stuff)

Comment: Thanks for catching that jkb, it's been a long morning and I'm mixing my tools up.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this. Can you provide the versions you are using? If you installed via RPM you can check with: 
rpm -qa | egrep -i 'redhawk|uhd'

and paste the output.

If you are installing via source let me know what versions you've cloned or how you cloned the repos.

Answer (score 0):

REDHAWK is packaged with the `uhd` package for the USRP. If you wish to modify the USRP_UHD REDHAWK Device source code, you will need to install the `uhd-devel` package as well (`sudo yum install uhd-devel`). Otherwise, the USRP_UHD won't compile and you'll see the errors you mentioned in the REDHAWK IDE.

REDHAWK 1.10 (and 2.0.1) is currently packaged with uhd 3.5.3, while the X310 USRP requires a newer version of uhd. I recommend updating to uhd 3.7.3 because anything more recent will likely have dependency conflicts (due to boost). With that said, the USRP_UHD REDHAWK Device is only tested with the USRP N210 hardware, and your mileage may vary with the X310 hardware.

To update to 3.7.3, follow instructions here: http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_build_guide.html. You may need to uninstall the existing uhd version, which will uninstall the REDHAWK USRP_UHD Device (and something called `redhawk-devices` in REDHAWK 2.0 and later), which is fine since you're rebuilding and installing both uhd and the USRP_UHD yourself.